# How to split string value using c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I want to split this `2015-08-11 10:59:41.830` value which is in datetime datatype format and convert it to the following format using c# asp.net.

`August 11, 45 minutes ago`

The given datetime(`i.e-2015-08-11 10:59:41.830`) will compare with the current datetime and display like the above format.Please help me to do this.

Comment: `45 minutes ago` is static or something? How do you calculate this 45 minute part exactly?

Comment: You can subtract current time and previous time via `DateTime` subtract function and then you can format the string using "MMMM dd {0} minutes" where {0} is `elapsed` values

Comment: @ Soner : No,It should noot static.As i said that given time will compare with current time and result will come.

Comment: check this value `2015-08-11 10:59:41.830` then i need to convert to this format `August 11, 45 minutes ago`.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to parse your date using [`DateTime.Parse(string s)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) and once you have that, you take the current date (`DateTime.Now`) and subtract from it the parsed date.

This should yield a [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) struct. Assuming that both of the dates will refer to the same date, you can then construct your string by taking the pieces you need from the parsed date (Day and Month) and from the time span (Hours, minutes and seconds).

Answer (score 0):

For your specific format you can try `ParseExact() "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Given that previous and and now is the same day
    DateTime previous = DateTime.ParseExact("2015-08-18 10:59:41.830", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    double value = now.Subtract(previous).TotalMinutes;

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:MMMM dd}, {1} minutes ago", now, (int)value));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

npinti already [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32065331/447156) it, here the code part;

```
string s = "2015-08-18 10:59:41.830";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    var ts = dt - DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1} minutes ago", 
                        dt.ToString("MMMM dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        ts.Minutes);
}
```

I run this code `2015-08-18 09:50` in my local time and it's generate `August 18, 9 minutes ago` as a result.

Remember, [`Minutes` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.minutes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) represents minute component of the TimeSpan object and it's range is from `-59` to `59`. If you wanna get all minutes based on TimeSpan object value, you can use [`TotalMinutes` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (or even as `(int)ts.TotalMinutes`).

Comment: If the given date time will be in datetime format then ?

Comment: @satya I don't understand your comment. What do you mean by _will be in datetime format_ exactly?

Comment: I mean the given value is already in datetime datatype,Is it important to parse this ?

Comment: @satya If you have already a `DateTime`, just use it. You will not to parse it. If you have a `string` that matches standard date and time format of your `CurrentCulture`, you can directly use `DateTime.Parse` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need this

```
  var yourString = "2015-08-11 10:59:41.830";
  var oldDate = DateTime.ParseExact(yourString, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  //The above two steps are only for if you have date in `string` type, but if you have date in `DateTime` format then skip these.
  var difference = DateTime.Now - oldDate; 
  //here old date is parsed from string or your date in `DateTime` format

  var result = string.Format("{0:MMMM dd}, {1} minutes ago", oldDate, difference.Minutes);
```

Comment: @satya Thanks for suggestion, I have edited my post.

Comment: @satya Replace your date with `oldDate`